# Python Modules Safe?

Tags: python, installation, module, malware-detection

I'm not a professional at recognizing security in Python modules, but is one of these Python modules possibly dangerous or contains malware?

altgraph                  0.17.3
atlassian-python-api      3.39.0
attrs                     23.1.0
auto-py-to-exe            2.36.0
bottle                    0.12.25
bottle-websocket          0.2.9
certifi                   2023.5.7
cffi                      1.15.1
chardet                   5.1.0
charset-normalizer        3.2.0
cryptography              41.0.2
Deprecated                1.2.14
Eel                       0.16.0
exceptiongroup            1.1.2
future                    0.18.3
gevent                    23.7.0
gevent-websocket          0.10.1
greenlet                  2.0.2
h11                       0.14.0
idna                      3.4
isodate                   0.6.1
jwt                       1.3.1
lxml                      4.9.3
oauthlib                  3.2.2
outcome                   1.2.0
pefile                    2023.2.7
Pillow                    10.0.0
pip                       23.1.2
platformdirs              3.8.1
plyer                     2.1.0
pycparser                 2.21
pyinstaller               5.13.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2023.5
PyJWT                     2.7.0
pyparsing                 3.1.0
pypiwin32                 223
PySocks                   1.7.1
pystray                   0.19.4
pytz                      2023.3
pywin32                   306
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.2
requests                  2.31.0
requests-file             1.5.1
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0
selenium                  4.10.0
setuptools                65.5.0
six                       1.16.0
sniffio                   1.3.0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0
trio                      0.22.2
trio-websocket            0.10.3
urllib3                   2.0.3
whichcraft                0.6.1
win10toast                0.9
winotify                  1.1.0
winsdk                    1.0.0b9
wrapt                     1.15.0
wsproto                   1.2.0
zeep                      4.2.1
zope.event                5.0
zope.interface            6.0

Is there a way to find out this information in a simple manner?

I have installed the modules, but I'm unsure whether these modules are truly secure.

Comment: If you don't trust the module authors, why would you trust random people on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Robert Malicious attacks on PyPi packages sometimes happen. The question is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

PyPi will remove malicious code immediately, so there isn't a chance that **known** malware will be found in those dependencies.

If you are worried that a particular package may have unknown malware, you can use `sysdig` to look into what events are occurring when you install the package. This is a ton of work, but look at this article for some pointers: https://jordan-wright.com/blog/post/2020-11-12-hunting-for-malicious-packages-on-pypi/

To determine if the code the run is possibly dangerous, or has a vulnerability you can use pip-audit: https://github.com/pypa/pip-audit

To install

```
pip install --upgrade pip pip-audit
```

It works best with virtual environments by reading the requirements.txt file. If you have the source installed in a virtual environment you can use

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You could also just write those files above manually into a requirements.txt but I don't recommend that. It would be in the form:

```
altgraph==0.17.3
atlassian-python-api==3.39.0
```

Once you have your requirements.txt run the following command:

```
pip-audit --requirement requirements.txt
```